# Duplicate on global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute

Tags: c#

I have two dbml - two different connections string, 2 tables in the same names (one for each data base) and getting errors for all of thems that are duplicates, why?

first table:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="DTS_Online.dbo.CategoryVariants")]
```

second:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name= "LeumiApp.dbo.CategoryVariants")]
```

and all the second table and functions marked as duplicate

[image: Errors like]

Comment: You should be more precise and develop a bit more your question. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @TzipPerkal it's not complaining about the table attribute being duplicated. It is complaining about the class name `partial class CategoryVariant`. You can change their namespace so they are treated as different classes